# Control tree does not match viewstate during the previous request

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

Im debugging a quite complex system i did not code. On a post back i get this error:

```
Exception: Failed to load viewstate. The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request. For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.
```

Im not very familiar with how the viewstate loads and works. The code builds up some grid view and controls dynamicaly and inserts them into a placeHolder called **phCallsDynamicGridHolder**

The code that creates the exception is always something similar to this:

```
HtmlGenericControl summary = createNewCallsSummary(calls);
GridView gv = createGridView(calls, "Calls", width);
phCallsDynamicGridHolder.Controls.Add(summary);
phCallsDynamicGridHolder.Controls.Add(gv);
phCallsDynamicGridHolder.Controls.Add(createNewCallsTotalSummary());
```

Is anyone familiar with what causes this kind of exception? The page is almost 2000 lines of code, i will past as much as needed upon request.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to load viewstate. The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795994/failed-to-load-viewstate-the-control-tree-into-which-viewstate-is-being-loaded)

Answer (score 0):

Psychically debugging, I would guess you are doing that dynamic control creation on *every* request; you may want to try changing the code so you only do that dynamic control creation within:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    // here
}
```

Comment: Nope. Its not triggered in Page_Load except within a Is Not Postback if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable ViewState for this page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind=" #####.aspx.cs" Inherits="#####" EnableViewState="false"%>
```