# How to clear viewstates in ASPX pages?

Tags: asp.net

I have an aspx page with some controls on it, I removed them, but then I get this error when I visit the page:

```
Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadViewStateRecursive(Object savedState)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadChildViewStateByIndex(ArrayList childState)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadViewStateRecursive(Object savedState)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadChildViewStateB...
```

Does anyone know what's going on and how can I delete any view states? Would something like an IS reset do it?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795994/failed-to-load-viewstate-the-control-tree-into-which-viewstate-is-being-loaded]

Comment: I still don't get how to clear it.